# SSIS PACKAGE META DATA INFORMATION

Tags: ssis

I need to investigate name of the  package which is deployed in SSISDB.

I have physical path and stored procedure used by the package.

Can anyone please help me to get package name or other information if we have a path or stored proc which is refereed in a package.

I am searching in different views in ssisdb such as [catalog].[event_messages].

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do search for package contents within SSISDB catalogue. Package source texts are stored encrypted there.
So, you have to import projects from SSIS Catalogue to SSIS Solution, and do the find/grep in .dtsx files.

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest doing a search for text using something link grepWin to look for the text of the stored procedure name in the development folder in which you have all the package development files.